# django model for city and places

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a real estate app, where I have models for properties, cities and places e.g.

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cities"


class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address


class Property(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish',verbose_name=_('Slug'))
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default='draft'
    )
```

This is how it looks in the admin

[admin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISId.png)

The problem is both these fields (city & places) are independent, i.e. you can choose London in the city and select a location from a different city. I'm fairly new to django models (or databases), but do you think I should change the `address` to just a `CharField` in the Property class? How does that relate to the `city`?

Ideally I want the autocomplete feature of the 'Google Places API' in both 'City' & 'Location' fields so that user can select both from the API results and then save the result in the database (when Agents will be adding properties) or do a db search using the selected city/location.

I have tried [django-google-places](https://bitbucket.org/alexhayes/django-google-places) but not sure how to incorporate that into a model field just like I want. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the Property model you do not need to set City as a Foreign key as it is already referenced to a city via the Location foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove `city` field from your Property class because location contains city in it.

To retrieve property city you can do something like this:

**models.py**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    # *Your codes here*

    # *define new method*
    def get_city(self):
        return self.location.city()
```

And then you can use this method every where you need:

**admin.py**

```
class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'slug', 'address', get_city, 'status']
```

or:

```
>>> A = Property.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> A.get_city()
```